# VS Post Build Event

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Need to write a post build event in VS 2010 project that copy just the dll and pdb to ....\MainProject\Debug

For some reason that I cannot explain the output path does not work.Nothing gets written.It used to.

How Can I do it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the post build event that you currently have?

Comment: Add line "echo on" to the beginning of Post Build command. This helps to understand what happens.

Comment: Does your path include a white space or another special character like '+'? Build events often fail because some double quotes are missing ...

Comment: I have nothing as post build yet.I want to have a postbuild as a temp fix for my output path not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you've set `Run the post-build event` setting to `When the build updates the project output`?

Comment: Depending on your project type you might find it on Project setting page, under Build Events tab but if youre just trying to redirect output of your project to some directory, the best way is by changing Output path under the build tab of the project settings.

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild in VS 2010 supports a better way of hooking up Before/After events:

```
<Target Name="StartDeployAdditionalDependencies" AfterTargets="Build">
    <!-- ... Do stuff ... -->
</Target>
```

See the following for further details:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msbuild/build-extensibility-with-net-framework-4)